# Firefox basic modification

Tags: c++, c, firefox, client

I have to modify firefox to make it an automated client for testing some personal servers.

I have to:
1.Have firefox connect normaly, send the GET HTTP, and run all scripts on that web page. 
2.Firefox does not display the page but save it to a file. 
I have not yet red the documentation, or the source, sorry.
 I want some hints on what functions firefox uses for this actions. Also this functions should be like an internal API, I mean that I should always find the functions in the version n+1. I also want to remove all the junk that remains and I not use, this will probably be an ugly task.

 Also I want some hints on the memory structure of firefox. Example: How do I access the variables that are available for the client side scripts firefox will run. What about the cookies.

Thank you.

Comment: Let us know once you've read the documentation.

Comment: @JoshJordan That will take a while, I wanted this stuff to be a quick hack but it seems it will take much more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the internal code of Firefox you should try implementing what you need in an extension. Better yet, use something already created, like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

You generally don't get useful answers to general questions like this.

Comment: I had to post it general-like.

Comment: You could just write some macros using the iMacros Firefox addon: http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/